# Deploying monorail web apps in monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop, castle-monorail, xsp

This question is specific to MonoDevelop I think.

I've got a test monorail solution that works fine when I run it from monodevelop but I'm having a problem when I use 'Deploy to web'.

I think the issue is that all of my NVelocity view files (inside a 'View/' directory) are being embedded into the assembly and xsp4 is expecting them to actually be copied to the deployment directory?

Can I either tell Monorail/NVelocity to find the views inside of this assembly or is there an easier way to tell Monodevelop to copy all files under a top level directory (like Views) to the deployment directory?

I see that I can explicitly set deployment properties for each file but I haven't been able to get that to work. When I set it to 'Include in deploy' and to 'Use project relative path' it puts them inside of "/bin/Views/". Then when I run xsp4 from '' it is expecting Views to be relative to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to right click the files in your view folder and select Build Action "Content" then they are copied to the same folder structure in your deployment directory when you do "Deploy to Web". However this might be a little tricky if they are in a referenced project, but then you can adjust your viewPathRoot in your monorail view engine configuration to point to the right place.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I wasn't even looking at build actions. I was expecting the solution to be part of the 'Deployment' properties.